# Rails where condition adding parantheses causing syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created the exact query I wanted in mysql which works fine:

```
SELECT 
    tasks.* 
FROM
    tasks 
    INNER JOIN 
        leads
        ON leads.id = tasks.taskable_id AND tasks.taskable_type = "Lead"
WHERE 
    tasks.taskable_id IN (1, 2) 
    AND 
    (
        tasks.id = 
        (
            SELECT tasks.id 
            FROM tasks
            WHERE tasks.taskable_id = leads.id 
            AND
            tasks.taskable_type = "Lead"
            AND 
            appointment_status = 1
            ORDER BY created_at asc
            LIMIT 1
        )
    )
```

I spent the past 2 hours trying to translate this into ActiveRecord syntax but I cannot get it working. The closest I got is this:

```
Task.joins(:lead_tasks)
    .where(
        taskable_id: self.all.map(&:id)
    )
    .where(
        "tasks.id = (?)",
        Task.select(:id)
                .where("tasks.taskable_id = (?) AND tasks.taskable_type = ?", self.where(appointment_status: APPOINTMENT_STATUS[:yes]).map(&:id), "Lead")
                .order('created_at asc')
                .limit(1)
     )

  class Task
  belongs_to :lead_tasks, -> { where(tasks: { taskable_type: "Lead"}) },foreign_key: :taskable_id, class_name: "Lead"
```

But this generates sql that looks like this:

```
SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` 
INNER JOIN `leads` ON `leads`.`id` = `tasks`.`taskable_id` 
AND 
`tasks`.`taskable_type` = 'Lead' 
WHERE `tasks`.`taskable_id` IN (1, 2) 
AND 
(tasks.id = (SELECT  `tasks`.`id` FROM `tasks`  WHERE (tasks.taskable_id = (1,2) 
AND tasks.taskable_type = 'Lead')  ORDER BY created_at asc LIMIT 1));
```

The difference is Rails adds the extra () after the WHERE causing the following syntax error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

How can I force Rails not to add the ()? Or better yet, what is the proper way to build this subquery in Rails?

Comment: Try using it like `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("your_sql_query")`.

Comment: @Vucko is that really the best solution? There is no way to do this with Active Record? Because I need this query to return an active record relation./

Comment: When I had some complex SQL querys, I run it with `Base.connection.execute` - I didn't had the time to look for a ActiveRelation solution. But, I would say that this would be your last solution. However, wait for a while, maybe someone posts an aswer with ActiveRecord. +1 Nevertheless :)

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I posted solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this:

```
sql = Task.select(:id).where("tasks.taskable_id = leads.id AND tasks.taskable_type = 'Lead' AND appointment_status = 1").order("created_at asc").limit(1).to_sql
Task.joins(:lead_tasks).where(taskable_id: self.all.map(&:id)).where("tasks.id = (#{sql})")
```

This returns an ActiveRecord Relation of task objects which was what I needed.